# how to use serial port class [C# ] in java

Tags: c#, java, serial-port

I want to use serial port class and its function in my java application for rs232 communication. I know there are libraries for java for communicating rs232 but i want to use Microsoft windows dll containing the class 'serial port' [i think it is in System.dll in .net framework] 
So can somebody please tell me how can i use it, if any kind of example for this???

Answer (score 4):

This is what I like to call a ["Shoe or Bottle?"](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx) question. Do not go mixing Java and .NET, it **can** be done but **there are better easier ways** to do what you want to do.

Do one of two things:

1. Write your entire project in a .NET language and use the [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class built in with .NET.
2. Write your entire project in java and use the [SerialPort](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/SerialPort.html) class built in with java.

Please do not try and mix and match the two, it is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

[`SerialPort Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)

There's an example for usage for `SerialPort` class there. You can then create your .dll and access it trough COM. You can check out this thread for more info:

[Consuming a .Net library via COM or direct integration in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468198/consuming-a-net-library-via-com-or-direct-integration-in-java)

Although, this is a complicated process and just like others here, I would strongly recommend that you only use one technology in this case.